# When does a delivery callback called with an error in confluent kafka client?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-python

The Confluent Kafka library (python version in this case) has a produce method which takes a delivery callback function:

```
kafka_producer.produce(topic=topic,
                            key=key,
                            value=value,
                            on_delivery=delivery_callback)
```

This callback is called whether the message was successfully delivered or not:

```
def delivery_callback(err, msg):
```

I want to know what are the scenarios when this delivery callback is called with an error? I tried to shut down the kafka broker server and then produce and flush the message. Still the callback was not called with the error, rather the next time I did flush with the Kafka broker running, the successful delivery callback for the previous message came first.

So how can I have error callback?

Answer (score -3):

Produce message to topic. This is an asynchronous operation, an application may use the callback (alias `on_delivery`) argument to pass a function (or lambda) that will be called from `poll()` when the message has been successfully delivered or permanently fails delivery.

---

Currently message headers are not supported on the message returned to the callback. The `msg.headers()` will return `None` even if the original message had headers set.

Comment: Copy pasting from the documentation does not constitute an answer